# Get row with highest comment count

Tags: sql, content-management-system

I am making a custom CMS and can't quite get something to work. The featured slider needs to get the 3 "most commented" posts.

How would I do this?

Comment: A lot more context is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess but have you tried...
Group by COUNT
not tested but something like...
SELECT post.post_title, COUNT(*) FROM comment WHERE comment.postID = post.postID GROUP BY post.post_title;

Comment: Can you please explain the sql to me?